# TextView Text Cutting

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am using `cardview` for displaying text in one of my android quote application. My text is cut from left and right side...I have tested padding, margin etc but not working. You can see text cutting in the image

[image]

My XML looks like below...

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/quoteCard"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/newbackg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardBackground"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/newbackg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/quoteCardActionView"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
                    android:text="The price of success is hard work, dedication to the job at hand, and the determination that whether we win or lose, we have applied the best of ourselves to the task at hand."
                    android:textSize="@dimen/newMainText"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

New Image look like below

[image]

Please check and let me know if someone can help me to solve the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Set **Margin Left and Right** to `TextView`

Comment: I think it's because of background you are using inside `card view` and `image view`. Can you post your background image ? Try once by removing background from `card view` and check.

Comment: @jaydroider there no any changes....

Comment: please paste your image @drawable/newbackg @Manisha

Comment: but actually nice quote! and check my ans.

Comment: and also paste your quote

Comment: @NileshRathod its just jpg image...not any xml

Comment: @ManishaPandey add that image in quetion that i want to tell you and also paste your textmsg

Comment: better create xml for your background

Comment: what is your text size ??

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan its 18sp

Comment: @ManishaPandey  May be you have given padding or margin in viewpager.

Comment: @Vishvadave there no any margin..padding in viewpager

Comment: @ManishaPandey your code is perfect actually. It works perfectly in my system. check my answer. try it once.

Comment: I guess your code is fine. it works fine for everyone here..just check with real device..

Comment: @ManishaPandey try to run your program in to physical  your device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your `XML`.

Use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/quoteCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/quoteCardActionView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="સફળતાની કિંમત હાર્ડ કામ છે, નોકરી પરના સમર્પણને, અને નક્કી કરીએ છીએ કે આપણે જીતી કે ગુમાવું, અમે હાથમાં કાર્ય માટે શ્રેષ્ઠ જાતને લાગુ કર્યો છે."
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Check screen shot of my device with above XML used.

[image]

Comment: @ManishaPandey Let you check my device screen shot. I have added it.

Comment: @jaydroider he has background as image

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan I know bro but i have already asked about it. You can check my comment in OP. But hasn't posted image yet. OP can make changes and add image in above xml.

Comment: @jaydroider Please check my question...I have updated image

Comment: @ManishaPandey check my answer.I have used image as background.

Comment: @ManishaPandey I need your background image that you are using currently. so that i an download that and setup to my xml.

Comment: @jaydroider I have removed image background...but still issue...means there no any issue with background :(

Comment: @ManishaPandey Once try to clean and rebuild your project and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing `android:padding="8dp"` for `LinearLayout`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/quoteCard"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/newbackg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardBackground"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/newbackg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/quoteCardActionView"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
                    android:text="The price of success is hard work, dedication to the job at hand, and the determination that whether we win or lose, we have applied the best of ourselves to the task at hand."
                    android:textSize="@dimen/newMainText"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There no anychanges :(

Comment: i think you should check margin padding.

Comment: Yes, I too feel she has to verify padding and margins properly, Up-vote if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/quoteCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/disha"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardBackground"
            android:background="@drawable/disha"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/quoteCardActionView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="સફળતાની કિંમત હાર્ડ કામ છે, નોકરી પરના સમર્પણને, અને નક્કી કરીએ છીએ કે આપણે જીતી કે ગુમાવું, અમે હાથમાં કાર્ય માટે શ્રેષ્ઠ જાતને લાગુ કર્યો છે."
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am facing still same issue...there no any changes...just imageview is gone

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/quoteCard"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cardBackground"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/quoteCardActionView"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
                    android:text="સફળતાની કિંમત સખત મહેનત, હાથમાં કામ માટે સમર્પણ, અને નક્કી કરીએ છીએ કે આપણે જીતીએ કે ગુમાવવું છે, અમે સફળતા માટેના મૂલ્ય પર કાર્ય માટે જાતને શ્રેષ્ઠ રીતે લાગુ પાડીએ છીએ, મહેનતનું કામ, હાથે કામ માટે સમર્પણ , અને તે નક્કી કરે છે કે આપણે જીતીએ કે ગુમાવું, અમે હાથમાં કાર્ય માટે શ્રેષ્ઠ જાતને લાગુ કર્યો છે."
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this textview, add the left,right padding.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:text="સફળતાની કિંમત હાર્ડ કામ છે, નોકરી પરના સમર્પણને, અને નક્કી કરીએ છીએ કે આપણે જીતી કે ગુમાવું, અમે હાથમાં કાર્ય માટે શ્રેષ્ઠ જાતને લાગુ કર્યો છે."
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: you have to give margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Create XML for Background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#555994"
        android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners
        android:radius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

your.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/quoteCard"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardBackground"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/tests"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/quoteCardActionView"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
                android:text="વિશ્વાસ બધા પર ના કરો સાહેબ
કારણ કે સાકર અને મીઠા નો રંગ એક જ હોય છે."
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: in your imageview just add adjustviewbound true..and check it